# React fetch('http://localhost:3000/profile/:id')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

as the title says, I am trying to fetch this URL from node/express server. The route is working fine in Postman, so I believe it tells me the mistake is in my fetch method.

my code:

```
onSubmitSave = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/profile/:id', {
        method: 'put',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: this.state.name, 
            telephone: this.state.telephone,
        })
    })
    .then(response =>  response.json())
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

}
```

I would be glad if anyone could help me with that.

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: Do you have  cors enabled on the local server?

Comment: `:id` is a variable for your server, not your browser. For example `fetch('http://localhost:3000/profile/123')` then on your express server, `req.params.id` will be equal to `123`

Comment: this one: cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id" for model "Voting"

Comment: @YuriNunes what do you think that error is trying to tell you?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see your `:id` being replaced by any string interpolation. You might be looking for something like this:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/profile/${this.id}`)
```